# Cloning and appending modified Cloned JS element does not work as intented

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, clone

I have the code below:

```
var SIT = window.setTimeout(function(){{
            var element = window.clonedElement.cloneNode(true);
            alert(element.getAttribute(data-login-name));
            element.removeAttribute('data-login-name');
            element.setAttribute('data-login-name', '{0}');
            element['data-login-name'] = '{0}';
            window.clearTimeout(SIT);
            alert(element.getAttribute(data-login-name));
            return document.getElementById('student-buttons').appendChild(element);
            window.clearTimeout(SIT);
```

When i try to clone + modify + append it behaves like clone + append.

Basically after i clone the element and appendChild() it works as it should, but when I try to clone + modify + append it keeps the old values. The alert() function shows up the correct modified data so the data inside the element is good. Why in the UI it's loaded with the old data like in the clone+append situation?

How can I make the appendChild() see the modified data?